# How to resolve this (IMO) unexpected behaviour in NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Basically I have this function in my categories model file:

```
Categories.prototype.delSubcategory = function(categoryId, subcategory, callback) {

    var finalSub = "subcategories." + subcategory;
    finalSub = '"' + finalSub + '"';

    this.getCollection(function(error, category_collection) {

        if(error) callback(error);

        else {

            category_collection.update(

                {_id: category_collection.db.bson_deserializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(categoryId)},
                { $unset : { finalSub: "" } },
                function(error, subcategory) {

                    if(error) callback(error);

                    else callback(null, subcategory)

                }

            )

        }

    });

};
```

if I `console.log(finalSub)` I'll see `"subcategories.myvalue"` printed as expected. So when I use this within my application the function should update the document as expected, however it doesn't. neither does show any error. If I replicate a similar behaviour in the shell, it'll work and the document will update accordingly.

If, instead of using `{ $unset : { finalSub: "" } }` I use `{ $unset : { "subcategories.myValue": "" } }`, hard-coding the value in the function it does work, so the problem seems to occur only when I pass a string in a variable and I can't understand why.

Any ideas?

PS: Please note that in this case, the aforementioned is meant to delete an object inside an object, hence the empt "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create this object literal:

```
{ $unset : { finalSub: "" } }
```

You get:

```
{ "$unset": { "finalSub": "" } }
```

This clearly isn't what you want.  However, unless you expect the `$unset` part to throw a `ReferenceError`, it is consistent.  You're going to have to build that object differently:

```
updateObj = { $unset: {} }
updateObj.$unset[finalSub] = ""
```

Then you can use `updateObj` in place of the literal:

```
        updateObj = { $unset: {} }
        updateObj.$unset[finalSub] = ""
        category_collection.update(

            {_id: category_collection.db.bson_deserializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(categoryId)},
            updateObj,
            function(error, subcategory) {

                if(error) callback(error);

                else callback(null, subcategory)

            }

        )
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either as the mongo complains if I use the preceding code in the following structure: `{updatebj.$unset[finalSub] = ""}`. In fact I can't even use dot notation inside the object. It looks almost like the code inside the object is not being executed but simply passed as string.

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK You don't seem to understand how object literals work in javascript.  If you use the code I provided instead of using a literal, it will work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right, I'm new to js and still getting confused with things. I've tried your code and it didn't seem to work. Probably because I placed it wrong. How would the above function look like with your code in it? All my attempts have failed.

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK I've edited to show what you should put in the else block of that function.